# Select by Folder Name for Email Template in SOQL

Tags: soql

When I query for only a folder in Email Templates with this SOQL

```sql
SELECT FolderName,Name 
FROM EmailTemplate 
WHERE FolderName = 'Customer Returns
```

I get no data. However if I leave out the WHERE statement. I can see those Folders.
Customer Returns    Mismatched Order Ltr w URL Lee

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a really strange behavior.

Below query you mentioned in the question didn't work for me as well:

> SELECT Name, FolderName FROM EmailTemplate WHERE FolderName = 'Customer Returns'

But apparently when we change `FolderName` to `Folder.Name` in the where clause, the query works:

> SELECT Name, FolderName FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Folder.Name = 'Customer Returns'

I don't know why this works, looks like a bug to me.

Comment: I think FolderName is meant to be used only to display the value. Folder.Name is definitely the way I would query this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @sfdcfox, looking at the documentation of the [EmailTemplate](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_emailtemplate.htm) object, `FolderName` does has `Filter` property, so ideally filtering by `FolderName` should have also worked?

Comment: Yeah, it should. Perhaps a bug of some sort? I just did a test, apparently FolderName has a lower query cost than folder.name. It might be worth logging a case with Technical Support.

Answer (score -1):

Filter.Name works - I don't know why either.